# jquery - google analytics not pulling in the footer

Tags: jquery, html, google-analytics

I am trying to add Google Anlytics to all my html pages.The  below page  is called rates.html.

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script> 
    $(function(){
    $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
    });
  </script> 
 </head>
 <body>                                 
   <div id="footer"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

On my footer.html I have the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css" />
<title>Footer</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <p align="center">Numbers: +244 (0) 00000000 | Lodge: +244 (0) 00000000 <br />
  <a href="mailto:lodge@sidney.co.za%20" class="Copy_link1">lodge@sidney.co.za  </a>| <a href="mailto:reservations@sidney.co.za" class="Copy_link1">reservations@samara.co.za</a></p>
  <p align="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus temporibus sequi saepe eius dolorem iusto deleniti, numquam nemo provident sunt accusantium esse cum similique harum reprehenderit illum, facilis laudantium soluta!.</p>
  <p align="center"><a href="http://www.sidney.com/" class="Copy_link1">SEO Powered by Ruby Digital</a></p>
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)    {   i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)  [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-12813356-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see the paragraphs content.Problem is that I just realized that the rates.html and other html pages don't really pull the analytics because when I  view the page source,no analytics is shown.

How can I do for the google analytics do be displayed in my pages

Answer (score 0):

Put the analytics in its own js file. You cant render in a file with .load() that has js in it, only the html gets rendered, not the js that is in the file.

your rates.html would look something like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="analytics.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>                                 
        body content here
    </body>
</html>
```

then put your analytics code in a file called analytics.js

Comment: I can't do that. Like I mentioned, rates file is pf html extension. On the the php files it's all right using the includes. But on the html files it does not work that's why I was trying the jquery code.

Comment: ...Thanks in advance.I tried that before as first attempt and it didn't work either. I know it should work but for some reason it doesn't